# How to use JavaBeans datasource in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

How to use JavaBeans datasource in iReport?

Comment: The more effort you put into your question, the better the quality and quantity of the answers you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found few links for you. Hope these might help you. Check these out -

This link shows you how to design a simple report -
http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=66979

this is documentation of how to use datasource in ireport-
http://ireport.sourceforge.net/cap4.html